# In blender 3.x, why do some objects have restriction toggles and others do not?

Tags: modeling

Can anyone tell me why some objects in Blender 3.x have associated restriction toggles and others do not in the outline view (and the objects are also greyed out)?  Thx

[image]

Comment: Without any context or images of your outliner it's impossible to say. We need more details! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Added the picture.  Wondering why the right columns vary from object to object.  Thx

Comment: There's a detailed video about the outliner [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u918WfK3oac) which should help explain it.

Comment: @JohnEason It's a good basic tutorial about the _Outliner_ but it doesn't explain why there are no restriction toggles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is quite simple. As we can see in your screenshot, the object named "LegPermaMod_Inner.l" is a child of "LegPermaMod_Outer.l", that's why it is placed beneath the parent object in the hierarchy. The parent object is of course greyed out because it's set to be hidden in the viewport.

The reason the child object is greyed out and has no restriction toggles is because it is in a different collection than the parent object. As you can see in the screenshot below, I've parented the sphere to the cube, but the cube is in "Collection" and the sphere in "Collection 2". In "Collection 2" the sphere has the restriction toggles as well:

[image: child in different collection]